# How to send mails from plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am in need of sending emails to recipients from my oracle procedure, however i am restricted to use `UTL_MAIL` and `UTL_SMTP`. Other than these i am not aware of any other way of sending mails.

Also is tehre a way to connect to unix from oracle plsql code so that i can use `mailx -s` and trigger the mail.

Can you please help me here.

Comment: There are a lot of articles on the web about this, for example this one: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql

Comment: So you know of two ways which work, and which are robust (because using Oracle supplied libraries). Why would you want a third approach, especially one which requires building a brittle and potentially insecure call out to the OS?

Comment: Because the OP knows how to send mail with Unix' `mailx` and doesn't know how to use UTL_MAIL nor UTL_SMTP, @APC. Basically, the same reason why people who know only Oracle want to use it to e.g. move files between directories on the local hard disk. What does a DBMS have to do with *moving files*? Nothing. But, if your only tool is a hammer, then every problem looks like a nail. At least, that's what I think, and that doesn't have to be right.

Answer (score 2):

UTL_MAIL and UTL_SMTP are the supported way to generate e-mail from PL/SQL and should offer a less complicated design than executing a shell script. It would also be *much* more secure. That said, the following links describe several different ways to execute OS scripts from within PL/SQL:

- http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_execute_shell_script_plsql_procedure.htm
- https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/calling-shell-commands-from-plsql-1-1-129519.pdf
- https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9533837800346646784
- https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/shell-commands-from-plsql